# Android canvas freezes

Tags: javascript, android, canvas

I have a javascript application that runs in a canvas. It works on android, except that when you drag across the screen with your finger the whole web page freezes. Is there any way to stop this from occurring?

Comment: If you cover your canvas with a transparent div does the problem still occur? Just to see if it's touch on canvas element that is the issue.

Comment: Ill tryrhat when I get home, but I think the problem has to do with thescreen trying to scroll/ zoom. It locks up even when I drag my finger outside of the canvas.

Comment: Maybe you have some unnecessary `event.preventDefault()` call?

Comment: Your javascript have some unnecessary event.preventDefault();
 event.stopPropagation(); in touchHandler

Answer (score 3):

The way you represent your question its not show pretty rich of information .

the web apps have  some of the limitation to acquire the fully  feature  of android .

Your statment **I have a javascript application that runs in a canvas**  , in a first looks it seems you are used android canvas in your application .

here is the [link](http://j-query.blogspot.in/2010/11/android-html5-canvas-mashup.html)

which can help you to run html5 canvas in android

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you do in your code on a `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and MOVE... you should have some routine drawing the canvas. That routine shouldn't be interrupted by any other routine.

Not sure if this fixes your problem or provides any insight, but here goes;

For instance;

```
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  // fills the canvas with black
  canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
  // draw some stuff on it
  backGnd.draw(canvas);  
  basket.draw(canvas);
  for (int i = 0; i < AppleList.size();i++){
      AppleList.get(i).draw(canvas);
  }  
 }
```

The motionevent would be handled as follows (note the in-code Comment!) ;

```
 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

 if (!isTouchDisabled){
      if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

        // add code to pass the action down to the objects
           basket.handleActionDown((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
          }

          if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
           // the gestures

        // only pass the move events to the objects that were previously touched (so action down entails checking for
        // the location of the touch AND the object.. if they match, you set isTouched to true.

        if (basket.isTouched()) {
            // the basket was picked up and is being dragged
            basket.setX((int)event.getX());
            basket.setY((int)event.getY());

           }
          }

          if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
           // Check buttons
              if (btnMoreFruit.isTouched()){
                  btnMoreFruit.handleActionUp((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
                  btnMoreFruit.setTouched(false);
              }
              if (btnLessFruit.isTouched()){
                  btnLessFruit.handleActionUp(this.getContext(), (int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
                  btnLessFruit.setTouched(false);
              }

          }
 }
```

Comment: I am trying to write Javascript to run in the android browser. Unless I am really missing something, you gave me java to run in an android app. The problem would be pretty easy to solve if I was writing an app.

Comment: Ah.. Sorry, didn't get that. Can't help you there. Did you try different browsers? (FF, Opera, Dolphin) just to check and determine root cause?

Comment: i tried what I could on my kindle fire, nothing seemed to work fully, though some were better than others. I don't think its possible to fix the problem, but I figured I would give up some bounty to find out if someone had a magic solution.

It really is a major problem for web apps though.

Comment: So why not build a true Android app instead of web app?

Comment: We are building some android apps, but it would be nice if I could just make some of my existing HTML5 pages work on android. It's kind of frustrating that everything works except for this one problem.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you have in your code, there is potentially a lot of processing that takes place when someone drags their finger (or mouse) across a canvas. In painting apps, for example, the XY position of the user's focus is captured everytime it changes pixels. If the code inside each of these tiny events isn't light, the client will hang while it tries to catch up.

Comment: There is no extra code running when the finger is dragged. The code continues to run as normal, it just doesn't repaint the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Android is pretty bad on handling canvas and javascript. Probably this is why it also freezes.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDrPNXnH-rg